# Trying to remove all non-english characters from list of strings

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nltk

I have a list of dictionaries

```
Amazon 120 
b 19 
maji_opai 1 
am\xcd\x9ca\xcd\x89zon\xe2\x80\xa6 1 
\xcb\x99\xea\x92\xb3\xe2\x80\x8b\xcb\x99 1 
b'RT 46 
WorkingGIrl 1 
For 1 
people 1 
love 1 
REAL 1 
paperback 1 
THE 3 
PARIS 1 
EFFECT 1 
10 1 
right 1
```

and am having trouble getting rid of the characters and non-english words.The goal of the twitter scrape is to create a simple word frequency count.

Is there a best way to go about creating a loop and removing all the non-english words/ characters?

This code I used to create the wordcount dictionaries

```
wordcount={}

for word in lemma_list:
    if word not in wordcount:
        wordcount[word] = 1
    else:
        wordcount[word] += 1

for key in wordcount.keys():
    print ("%s %s " %(key , wordcount[key]))

print(type(wordcount.keys()))
   <class 'dict_keys'>
```

Comment: where is the `list` and where are the `dictionaries`?

Comment: Sorry. Just getting used to posting questions on here. I edited the code i used to get the list of dictionaries

Comment: you need to find a dictionary to compare against. Otherwise you'll be limited to just throwing out words with non-ASCII characters, which won't tell you if it's a real word nor if it's English or not. once you have that you could potentially investigate some sort of spell checking algorithm to account for misspellings, but that can get quite complicated quite fast.

Answer (score 0):

If by "english" character you mean ["ascii"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) then use `string.printable` which is a set of all ASCII printable characters

```
import string
ascii_chars = set(string.printable)  # speeds things up
def remove_non_ascii_prinatble_from_list(list_of_words):
    return [word for word in list_of_words 
            if all(char in ascii_chars for char in word)]
```

Or on a dictionary

```
def remove_non_ascii_prinatble_keys_from_dict(dict_of_words):
    return {key: value for key, value in dict_of_words.items() 
            if all(char in ascii_chars for char in key)}
```